# TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error with nginx-ingress and wordpress

Tags: php, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

i am facing a TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in my wordpress application. Below you can see some printscreens of my configuration:

[image: Nginx Ingress Config]

[image: Nginx ConfigMap]

[image: php-fpm proxy_pass]

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code in your question, this makes it easy for users to try out your code by copying it in their machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append to a ConfigMap a new  *server*  inside the  *http*  context using the  [http-snippet](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/01399dd62570bd101b51a9d132f47069d7df97c6/docs/user-guide/configmap.md#http-snippet).

For example:

```
...
data:
  ssl-redirect: "false"
  hsts: "true"
  server-tokens: "false"
  http-snippet: |
    server {
      listen 8000 proxy_protocol;
      server_tokens off;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

This will prevent overriding the original  `nginx.tmpl`, ensuring more compatibility in case of upgrade the Nginx Ingress version.

Please take a look: [ingress-too-many-redirects](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/71#issuecomment-369622493),  [too-many-redirects-with-reverse-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931256/too-many-redirects-with-reverse-proxy).

Useful article: [too-many-redirects-wp](https://undsgn.com/too-many-redirects-issue/#:%7E:text=What%20does%20%E2%80%9Ctoo%20many%20redirects,new%20one%20with%20a%20plugin.)